# Dragon Age:Origins Lothering Bandits on the Road Quest

Tags: dragon-age-origins

When i got to Lothering and attacked the bandits in the quest "Bandits on the Road" one of the options was "Come fight for me, I could use some soldiers" however this is not mentioned on the [wiki](http://dragonage.wikia.com/wiki/Bandits_on_the_Road).

What do you gain from this option, as appose to killing them or letting them go?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not mentioned in the wiki, my guess is that the bandits refuse to have anything to do with you in that regard. Having the dialog option does not mean that it will be accepted, even if it is not a persuasion or intimidation check. I haven't tried that option myself, but my guess would be that is declined and that you're left with two options - letting them go or killing them.

Comment: I have selected this option, and the bandit leader refuses. Saying, "We're not soldiers." Then you are with kill them or let them go.